# Convert excel formulas to latex equations

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to convert excel formulas to latex equations but not being able to, this is the code I am working with. In my example cell F3 is `=SQRT(D1+D2/D3*D5)` and the result of this code applied to that cell is `$\sqrt(D1 + D2 \div D3 \times D5)$`

However the result I am looking for would be `$\sqrt(1 + 2 \div 3 \times 5)$`
The actual cell values instead of the cell address. I am having a hard time trying to figure this out. Thanks in advance.

[image]

```vb
Function ConvertToLaTeX(formula As Range) As String
    Dim cellName As String
    Dim cellValue As String
    Dim latexFormula As String
    
    ' Replace Excel cell references with their values in LaTeX syntax
    latexFormula = formula.Formula
    For Each cell In formula.Cells
        If cell.HasFormula Then
            cellName = cell.Address(False, False)
            cellValue = cell.Value
            latexFormula = Replace(latexFormula, cellName, cellValue)
        End If
    Next cell
    
    ' Replace arithmetic operators and functions
    latexFormula = Replace(latexFormula, "=", "")
    latexFormula = Replace(latexFormula, "+", " + ")
    latexFormula = Replace(latexFormula, "-", " - ")
    latexFormula = Replace(latexFormula, "*", " \times ")
    latexFormula = Replace(latexFormula, "/", " \div ")
    latexFormula = Replace(latexFormula, "^", " ^ ")
    latexFormula = Replace(latexFormula, "SQRT", "\sqrt")
    
    ' Enclose the equation in LaTeX syntax
    ConvertToLaTeX = "$" & latexFormula & "$"
End Function
```

Comment: This looks quite nice, but how will you deal with curly brackets, like `1/(2+1/3)` should become `\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{3}}`? It might easily become quite complicated.

Answer (score 0):

After correcting the name of input parameter it becomes apparent where the bug was. Your `formula` is a range of cells (here consisting of only one cell `F3`). In the for loop you're looping through all cells in that range (cell `F3`), getting its address (`"F3"`) and value (`2.08...`). Replace doesn't find anything, therefore doesn't change anything.

To get precedents, use `cell.Precedents` syntax

```
Function ConvertToLaTeX(inputCell As Range) As String
    Dim latexFormula As String
    Dim cellAddress As String
    Dim cellValue As String

    latexFormula = inputCell.Formula

    For Each cell In inputCell.Precedents
        cellAddress = cell.Address(False, False)    'Format "A1"
        cellValue = cell.Value
        latexFormula = Replace(latexFormula, cellAddress, cellValue)
    Next cell

    ConvertToLaTeX = "$" & latexFormula & "$"
End Function
```